# Instance is disposed for shared resource when navigate back from barcode scan view

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, camera, zxing

I have a barcode scan feature in my app. There's a barcode button on main page, the user clicks that and goes to *barcode scan page*. But when it navigates back, I get a message box saying that:

```
This instance has been disposed. Possibly because another component required a shared resource.
```

I disposed the `PhotoCamera`, and canceled all the events in the `OnNavigatedFrom` method on the barcode scan page, but still get the same thing.

I stepped into the code and found something wrong with this method:

```
PhotoCamera _cam;
VideoBrush _videoBrush = new VideoBrush();
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
int _nbTry;
Result result = null;
void cam_AutoFocusCompleted(object sender, CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (result == null)
            { 
            try
            {
                _nbTry++;
                watch.Reset();
                watch.Start();

                while ((result == null) && (watch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 1500) && _cam != null)
                {
                    var binaryBitmap = GetBitmapFromVideo(_cam);
                    if (binaryBitmap != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            result = BarCodeManager.ZXingReader.decode(binaryBitmap);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            // Wasn't able to find a barcode
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (result != null)
                {
                    BarCodeManager._onBarCodeFound(result.Text);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (_cam != null)
                    {
                        _cam.Focus();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                BarCodeManager._onError(exc);
            }
        }
      }
```

There's an exception caught and following is the stack trace:

```
at Microsoft.Devices.Camera.InvokeAndRemapExceptions(Action a)
at Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera.get_IsFocusSupported()
at Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera.Focus()
at WP7.ScanBarCode.BarCode.cam_AutoFocusCompleted(Object sender, CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
at Microsoft.Devices.Camera.<>c__DisplayClass21`1.<SafeFireEvent>b__1f(Object ignored)
at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
at System.Threading.Timer.ring()
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: When the emulator is showing the message box, can you break and paste the callstack?

Answer (score 2):

The first time you leave you *barcode scan page*, you will probably dispose your `PhotoCamera`.

if you just dispose the `PhotoCamera` object, when you come back the *barcode scan page* you will get this error:

```
This instance has been disposed. Possibly because another component required a shared resource.
```

Try to dispose the `PhotoCamera` object and also all the events delegates, such `Initialized` or **related**:

```
// Release the camera object:
PhotoCamera.Dispose();

// Remove initialization event:
PhotoCamera.Initialized -= PhotoCamera_Initialized;

// For example, you must remove also the events linked to the camera management (e.g. when you press camera buttons):
CameraButtons.ShutterKeyHalfPressed -= CameraButtons_ShutterKeyHalfPressed;
```

Call this disposing code when you get into the `OnNavigatedFrom` event of your *barcode scan page*, and everything should work!